# Find two odd primes for which $(p-1)!≡-1\mod p^2$ where $p \le13$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Except brute force is there some way to solve this ?
One way we can solve it by using Wilson's theorem but I was not able to proceed much.

Comment: There are only $5$ primes to check...I think brute force really is the way to go.

Comment: Note: a quick search through the first 200 odd primes found only one example in addition to  these two $≤13$.

Comment: In the case, someone is interested, the next solution is $563$ and there is no further solution upto $10^5$. Googling "wilson prime" reveals that no further solution is known.

Comment: Wilson's theorem is not helpful if we restrict to the primes anyway. Every prime satisfies $$(p-1)! \equiv -1\mod p$$ but only very few primes satisfy this stronger congruence.

Comment: @Peter  that's amazing fact

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime) says no other solutions up to $2 \times 10^{13}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only $5$ odd primes $p$ with $p\leq13$. Computing $(p-1)!\pmod{p^2}$ for each of them can hardly be called brute force; I don't need pen and paper to check that
$$2!\not\equiv-1\pmod{9},\qquad 4!\equiv-1\pmod{25},\qquad 6!\not\equiv-1\pmod{49},$$
and the phrasing of the question suggests that *at least* one of $p=11$ or $p=13$ satisfies the congruence, so it suffices to compute $10!\pmod{121}$.

Comment: $10!\equiv (2×3×4×5)×(6×8×10)×(7×9)\equiv (-1)×(-4)×(63)\equiv 252\equiv 10\bmod 121$, no good.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks for checking, I couldn't be bothered. The phrasing of the question then implies that $(13-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{13^2}$, which I also can't be bothered to check.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: If they do, buy a lottery ticket.  Your luck would be on a roll.  (No, I did not downvote.)

Comment: @OscarLanzi Haha thanks for the reality check. Luckily commenting is free. Who knows, one day...